# PyMongo how to access hashed password without username

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, authentication, pymongo

im following ( https://github.com/ravi-sharma/flask-mongo/blob/master/app.py )
this as an example for a login page that im making, but im stuck.
this is the code he uses that im having trouble modifying to fit what im trying to do:

```
@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        users = mongo.db.users
        signin_user = users.find_one({'username': request.form['username']})

        if signin_user:
            if bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), signin_user['password'].encode('utf-8')) == \
                    signin_user['password'].encode('utf-8'):
                session['username'] = request.form['username']
                return redirect(url_for('index'))

        flash('Username and password combination is wrong')
        return render_template('signin.html')

    return render_template('signin.html')
```

in that version of the code, hes using a username to access the data from mongodb and then comparing the request form password to the password in the db. what im trying to accomplish is something similar but with tokens, instead of user/pass.
the issue im running into is, how do i access the token if theres no username for it?, and how can i compare the password request form to the document in collection.
heres what ive tried:

```
def account_login():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            tokens_collection = mongo.db.user_tokens
            user_login = tokens.find_one({'tokens': request.form['token']})
            if user_login:
                if bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['token'].encode('utf-8'), user_login['token']) == user_login['token']:
                    session['token'] = request.form['token']
                    return redirect(url_for("account"))
            flash('Token was incorrect, something went wrong')
            return redirect(url_for("account"))
        return redirect(url_for("account"))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"account login error: {e}")
```

the reason it wont work is cuz the values that the user input and the value in the db arent the same and idk howd compare them to get True value from if user_login.
please let me know if this needs more clarification, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i ended up just not hashing the token, works fine now. i think the issue was that for some reason the hashed password was being uploaded to mongodb as a binary and so i couldnt match it with hashed version of the token. and i couldnt figure out how to covert it from binary to hash.